# How is the relation $R$ on the power set of $A$ with $(x,y) \in R$ iff $x \subset y$ anti-symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> How is the relation $R$ on the power set of $A$ such that $(x,y) \in R$ if and only if $x \subset y$ anti-symmetric?

I am having trouble understanding how this relation is anti-symmetric. I understand that it is not symmetric as $x$ can be a proper subset of $y$ but that same set $y$ cannot be a proper subset of $x$. How is it that this relation is anti-symmetric. I am having trouble finding an example that would prove this and that ultimately if $(x,y)$ is in the relation and $(y,x)$ is in the relation, then $x = y$.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  It might be that you lack a definition of *anti-symmetric* and for that reason are "having trouble finding an example".  It would improve the Question to include the definition you want to use in the body of your post, or to expressly state that you would like a response to focus on how it should be (or *could be*) defined to make the claim true.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $(x,y) \in R$  then $x \subseteq y$. If you have $(y,x) \in R$, then $y \subseteq x$. Finally, if you have both, you must have $x \subseteq y \subseteq x$, which implies $x = y$.

Comment: I thought the same set cannot be a proper subset of itself so how does this work?

Comment: It doesn't. It fails the antisymmetry test. Did you get this problem from some book? You should ALWAYS check the notation at the end of the book or when it is presented in the book, since the notation can be diverse. My guess is that wherever you found this problem, the symbol is used to indicate that $x$ is a subset of $y$, not necessarily a proper subset. In which case you get the antisymmetry case, becase by definition two sets are equal iff both are subsets of each other

Comment: @JohnLarkos I also thought in your notation $x \subset y$ means $x \subseteq y$ not $x \subsetneq y$